# How do I make a function that opens the file for writing and let the user write to the file, and when the user write "stop", close the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

How do I make a function that 1. opens a file for writing, 2. Let the user write in text in a while loop that continue with new lines using("\n") to the user write "stop", and then the loop goes over to step 3. close the file.

So far I got this

```
def writesomething(filename):
    file1=open("randomfile","w")
    file1.write("")
    file1.close()
```

Comment: You acknowledge that a `while` loop is necessary in step 2; where is the loop in your code?

Comment: Yeah, that´s one of my questions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0):

First collect all the input, then `.join()` it with a `\n` then write it all at once.

```
text = []
user = input('Enter text to write to file (\'quit\') to end: ')
text.append(user)
while user != 'quit':
    user = input('Enter text to write to file (\'quit\') to end: ')
    text.append(user)
res = '\n'.join(text)
with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(res)
```

> ```
> Enter text to write to file ('quit') to end: vash
> Enter text to write to file ('quit') to end: the
> Enter text to write to file ('quit') to end: stampede
> Enter text to write to file ('quit') to end: quit
> chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/10.11$ cat text.txt
> vash
> the
> stampede
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function with a sentinel of `stop`, then join the resulting sequence strings with `'\n'` for output:

```
with open('randomfile', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(iter(input, 'stop')))
```